# The Python-Validating Sharepoint file has been uploaded

Tags: python, sharepoint, arguments, except

I'm uploading a file to `SharePoint` with a hyperlink to that file in my email to `stakeholders`. I need my Python code to validate that the file has actually been saved to the `SharePoint` location before it sends our stakeholders the email with the link..

Code as follows:

```
# upload csc file to sharepoint and send email notification
time.sleep(90)
try: 
    with open(archivePath, mode='rb') as file: 
        fileContent = file.read() 
    folder.upload_file(fileContent, "Daily_Points.xlsx")
except Exception as Argument:
    to = 'amy.jones@abc.com'
    subject = 'Sharepoint file not uploaded!'
    body = str(Argument)
    util.sendEmail(to, subject, body)
```

My Python code runs successfully and uploads my Sharepoint file but still sends me the exception email as follows:

```
Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sp16.ccx.carecentrix.com', port=443): read timed out. (read timeout = 3)
```

I can't find a way to increase the read timeout beyond 3 seconds. I’ve tried using time. sleep(90) before and after the test statement. Sometimes this works and doesn’t send the email, but most of the time it fails and sends the email.

Comment: if you want to wait for the event, then use a `while` loop. This will block until ready.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wait until the file exists, then you can use a `while` loop. the genric form would look something like this:

```py
import time

x = 0

# some condition needs to be satisfied to continue
checking = True

while checking:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(3)
    x = x + 1

    # test for the condition
    if x > 3:
        # condition satisfied
        checking = False


# continue with the code
print('send an email now...')
```

the generic output is this:

```
0
1
2
send an email now...
```

it is an excercise for the user to complete the task to its own customisation...

Comment: How would I check to see if the most recent file exists in Sharepoint?  I'd have to check if modified date is today - is that possible?

Comment: Getting some sort of modification date in a cross-platform way is easy - just call os.path.getmtime(path) and you'll get the Unix timestamp of when the file at path was last modified.